# Scroll to bottom of layout

Tags: xamarin.android, android-scrollview

I am trying to scroll to bottom of layout. I've got this piece of code, but it's not working

```
         ScrollView scrollView = view.FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.scrollViewHelper);
         scrollView.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to create an Action-based runnable, passing the Action as a parameter to the runnable .
You can refer to the following code:

```
        scrollView = FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.scrollView1);

        var runnable = new MyRunnable(async () =>
        {
            // Do whatever you need to do, including capturing of local vars, app/activity context, etc.
            await Task.Delay(500);
            scrollView.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down);
        });
        runnable.Run();
```

Code of class `MyRunnable`

```
public class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    readonly WeakReference<Action> actionRef;

    public MyRunnable(Action action)
    {
        actionRef = new WeakReference<Action>(action);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        actionRef.TryGetTarget(out Action action);
        action?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works exactly as expected:

```
await Task.Delay(500);
 scrollView1.FullScroll(FocusSearchDirection.Down);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).